# How to use Java and Twitter API to get tweets sent by given Twitter ID?

Tags: java, twitter, oauth, twitter4j

I want to use java and Twitter API to collect Twitter data for researching, especially to collect tweets sent by a given Twitter ID.
Now I can only collect my own tweets by using Twitter4j and OAuth setting. How could I get others tweets if I could not get their OAuth?

Comment: Please elaborate on what have you tried already and where are you stuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method you're looking for is:
getUserTimeline(java.lang.String screenName)
or:
getUserTimeline(long userId)

This will give you the latest 20 Tweets of the required user. So your code should look something like this:

```
Twitter twitterConnection = getConnection(); //I assume you already know how to init a connection
ResponseList<Status> results = twitterConnection.getUserTimeline("justinbieber");
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no restriction to collect others tweets, so what I mean is you don't need to have a specific authhentication token for this. Only restriction might be protected accounts owners because protected accounts don't allow anyone to get their tweets without establishing friendship association like following mechanism.

You can look at both dev.twitter.com and twitter4j sites how to do that. By the way, I recommend twitter4j. If you have further questions, let me know I can help more as well.

[Java4j Code Examples](http://twitter4j.org/en/code-examples.html)

Comment: Thanks very much for your answer and example link. Very useful!